# Is it possible to reuse the pre-defined controllers in spring annotation configured mvc projects?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

Is it possible to reuse the predefined controllers, like the SimpleFormController, with annotation configured spring mvc projects?

I downloaded a project that looks like what I want; however, the writer did not use the annotations that are predefined in Spring.

The controller of the downloaded project:

```
package net.sourceforge.sannotations.example2;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import net.sourceforge.sannotations.annotation.Bean;
import net.sourceforge.sannotations.annotation.UrlMapping;

/**
 * User: Urubatan Date: 24/10/2006 Time: 08:49:09
 */
@Bean
@UrlMapping("/test")
public class ExampleController implements Controller {
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        return new ModelAndView("example", "message", request.getParameter("tainted"));
    }
}
```

The project is downloaded from [SourceForge](http://sannotations.sourceforge.net/examples.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make them part of the spring-context faily easily - just annotate the `@Bean` annotation with `@Component`, and spring will detect it as a spring bean. Like:

```
 @Component
 public @interface Bean { .. }
```

For the URL-mapping, however, you might want to use a custom [BeanPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) to handle the value of the annotation.

Comment: I see. So this is only possible with the customized annotations, right? There is no way to achieve this with the pre-defined annotations.

Comment: No, you have to somehow instruct spring how to identify the custom annotations.